# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (<my-project>.deps.json) was not found

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

When I run:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

It errors:

> Error:
>     An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (idb-dialog-flow.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'idb-dialog-flow', version: '1.0.0'
>       path: 'idb-dialog-flow.dll'

Here is a link to my project: https://github.com/islaam-database/chatbot.

How do I get this to work?

Edit: I forgot to mention that this project is an Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround. I created a new project under the same solution. It was a library class project. I ran the entity framework commands in that project and it worked. I then imported that project into my first project and the DB calls were successful.